# Biosphere flow name and category mismatch when importing a SimaPro export

Tags: python, brightway

I'm currently trying to import an external database into a standard Brightway2 project with ecoinvent 3.7 as a base. The external database is also based on ecoinvent and was created with SimaPro and exported as CSV from there.

```
import brightway2 as bw2
fp = 'external_db.CSV'
imp = bw2.SimaProCSVImporter(fp, "external_db")
imp.migrate('default-units')
imp.apply_strategies()
imp.match_database(fields=('name', 'unit', 'location'))
imp.match_database('ecoinvent 3.7', fields=('name', 'unit', 'location','reference product'))
imp.match_database('biosphere3', fields=('name', 'unit', 'location'))
imp.match_database('biosphere3', fields=('name', 'unit'))
imp.statistics()
```

Unfortunately the import can not be finished as there are some unlinked exchanges in the biosphere and technosphere.

```
1107 datasets
160649 exchanges
22160 unlinked exchanges
  Type biosphere: 1384 unique unlinked exchanges
  Type technosphere: 640 unique unlinked exchanges
```

It seems that the main problem is that currently the biosphere setup of Brightway2 uses only whats necessary for the ecoinvent database and the external database already uses some additional biosphere flows from the EF3.0 that do not exist in the standard Brightway2 biosphere.

How can I update the biosphere and the impact assessment methods to include the additional biosphere flows? Respectively is there a bw2 migration for the ecoinvent 3.7 or higher to the EF3.0 biosphere naming convention?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a simple answer here, unfortunately, though this is something we are working on. As you correctly stated, there are differences in both the nomenclature for elementary and intermediate flows (e.g. biosphere flows and activities), as well as additional elementary flows in SimaPro versus the Brightway default data from ecoinvent.

The easiest way to make progress right now is to switch completely to SimaPro lists, including all flows. This would mean not using the `bw2setup` but exporting the ecoinvent version from SimaPro as well as any LCIA methods you want. You would also need to adjust the default strategies in the SimaPro importers to exclude normalization with original ecoinvent standards.

By the way, there isn't really a "good guy" here - the changes that PRé makes to the ecoinvent data are mostly reasonable. The problem is that there are differences, without systematic patterns, meaning they are hard to match programmatically.

But we would like to be able to use SimaPro files in Brightway matching to the original ecoinvent data. This needs a project with funding, as it would not be fun hacking on new algorithms (for which people could volunteer their time), but rather manual examination and piecewise improvement of various different matching strategies. As it seems like you are in a position to fund some development in this area (in a consortium with other players), please feel free to contact [Cauldron](https://cauldron.ch/), as they could organize this work.